# Network Manager Ubuntu Server 20.04, ethernet device not managed. etc/network/interfaces blank

Tags: server

Exactly that. I know in previous Ubuntu Server versions the default eth device was controlled on startup and managed by a script in etc/network/interfaces.

My network manager only sees wifi network sources. in the past i used to disable each line. but now that file is blank.

How do I get Network Manager to use my eth connections.??

Thanks.

*UPDATE*

So to clarify, I'm using Server 20.04 as a media server. i'ts been a while since i used it. I have it as a media server & as my main AV/TV. I have installed KDE Plasma as a GUI. I cant access the ssh file sharing from other computers, but i can use ssh from my server to access other computers. i thought it had something to do with network manager not seeing my ethX.

Comment: Edit your question and show me `sudo lshw -C network` and `cat /etc/netplan/*.yaml` and I'll take a look for you. Start comments to me with @heynnema or I'll miss them.

Comment: @heynnema won't matter since the system in Ubuntu Server is **netplan** - OP indicates they want to use Network Manager to manage it per their question: "How do I get Network Manager to use my eth connections.??"

Comment: Dennis... is there a reason to use NetworkManager vs networkd (netplan)?

Comment: So to clarify, I'm using Server 20.04 as a media server. i'ts been a while since i used it. I have it as a media server & as my main AV/TV. I have installed KDE Plasma as a GUI. I cant access the ssh file sharing from other computers, but i can use ssh from my server to access other computers. i thought it had something to do with network manager not seeing my ethX.

Comment: When responding via comments, include @heynnema, as an example, at the start of the comments, so we'll get notified. Otherwise we'll miss your updates.

Comment: You didn't give me the requested data, or answer my question.

Comment: Is the SSH port open in your firewall?

Answer (score 1):

Ubuntu Server uses Netplan by default for configuration nowadays, `/etc/network/interfaces` is more or less phased out now.

You should consider using Netplan and configuring it properly, but per your question of "How do I get Network Manager to use my connections?" you have to *tell* Netplan to use Network Manager for your connections.

To do this, you will need to go into `/etc/netplan/` and remove the YAML files that're there, and put a new file in its place named `01-network-manager-all.yaml` with this configuration in it:

```
# Let NetworkManager manage all devices on this system
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: NetworkManager
```

Then you need to reboot your system.  **Upon reboot, however, Network Manager will be in charge, and if you have no configurations set for your interfaces yet, there is a chance your server will be unreachable remotely.  Make sure you have some type of emergency access shell or such to your system if it is a remote system and you don't have direct physical access to it.**

Once the system is rebooted, you can use Network Manager to configure the server's networking via `nm-tray` or the `nmcli` command line tool.  Unfortunately, however, **there is no GUI** on Server so you can't use the GUI configuration tools.

Comment: In a server installation, why would you recommend using NetworkManager? A proper .yaml file should fix this problem.

Comment: @heynnema reread OP's question and you can answer that question yourself: "How do I get Network Manager to use my eth connections.??"  Strong suggestion would be to read the question being asked by the OP before questioning the answers.  I don't agree with OP's want to use Network Manager, but if that's the question they're asking, that's what I'm answering :P

Comment: I read the question. You know that Ubuntu Server has no GUI by default, and by using NM, the user will have to use CLI commands to configure the network. That's why I asked the question. The user may not understand the implications of using NM vs networkd.

Comment: @heynnema That doesn't mean I'm not answering OP's question just because "they'll have to use CLI commands" - `nm-tray` actually uses the CLI so is still an option you know, and gives a TUI interface.  ANd I know this since Lubuntu uses that out of the box by default.

Comment: So to clarify, I'm using Server 20.04 as a media server. i'ts been a while since i used it. I have it as a media server & as my main AV/TV. I have installed KDE Plasma as a GUI. I cant access the ssh file sharing from other computers, but i can use ssh from my server to access other computers. i thought it had something to do with network manager not seeing my ethX.

Comment: @DennisBird that's because Network Manager is giving way to the Netplan system which is configuring your interfaces.  If you want to use the KDE GUI and Network Manager to manage your Ethernet device, you need to follow my answer to tell Netplan to let Network Manager manage all interfaces.  Otherwise you're going to have to adjust things on the command line via Netplan YAML files and such.